# How to convert datetime from decimal to “%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S” given the time origin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I did my search around but I couldn't find an answer that satisfies my problem.

I am using python 3.7 and I need to convert a series of decimal numbers into datetime object in the form `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. While doing so I need to consider an origin point, for example:

`t = 0.000000`  equals to `2016-06-25 00:00:00`

`t = 0.010417`  equals to ..... ?

and so on. I know that in my decimal time the integer part is day since start, decimal part is fraction of day.

I have found an answer using R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161984/how-to-elegantly-convert-datetime-from-decimal-to-d-m-y-hms/). I also think that I might need to use the class method `date.fromordinal(ordinal)`or something similar but I cannot figure it out how to do it.

This is what I have tried so far:

example `t = 1.010416`

```
import datetime as DT
from datetime import timedelta  
day = int(x)
datetime_object = DT.datetime.strptime("2016-06-25 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
python_datetime = DT.datetime.fromordinal(day) + timedelta(days=datetime_object.day-1)
```

I get:

> datetime.datetime(1, 1, 25, 0, 0)

But I cannot add the year 2016 nor the month. Also, for every case in which `int(t) = 0`, I get:

> ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: @glibdud I have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to leave a clear answer here, taking into account my comments on the other answers:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

base_date = datetime(2016, 6, 25)
deltas = (2.34857, 0.010417, 1.010416)

for delta in deltas:
    print((base_date + timedelta(delta)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

That code yields the following ouput:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> 
>>> base_date = datetime(2016, 6, 25)
>>> deltas = (2.34857, 0.010417, 1.010416)
>>> 
>>> for delta in deltas:
...     print((base_date + timedelta(delta)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
... 
2016-06-27 08:21:56
2016-06-25 00:15:00
2016-06-26 00:14:59
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`timedelta` stores its data in this format: `(DAYS, SECONDS)` so you can calculate it easily:

```
import datetime

t = 2.34857

# Full days
days = int(t)

# Part of a day
part_of_day = t - int(t)
seconds = int(part_of_day * 24 * 60 * 60)

# Calculate the time delta
dt = datetime.timedelta(
    days=days,
    seconds=seconds
)

# Add t-delta to the first day
first_day = datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 25)
current_time = first_day + dt
current_time
```

will return:

`datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 27, 8, 21, 56)`

Then you can convert it to a string with this function:

`datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

`'2016-06-27 08:21:56'`

---

**Edit 1:** Instead of constructing the timedelta by days-seconds, one can use just float days as parameter (thanks to accdias!):

`dt = datetime.timedelta(days=t)`

Comment: There is no need to break ```t``` into the integer and decimal parts and the conversion stuff. Just pass it as days for ```datetime.datetime()```, it will do the right thing.

Comment: @vumux, my pleasure.

Comment: Another point: ```current_time``` in your code is already an instance of ```datetime.datetime```. With that in mind you just need ```current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')```.

Comment: I used it to show the existance of `datetime` object. Of course my code can be shortened. But I prefer to write more for someone to understand more :)

Comment: @vurmux Thanks a lot! I noticed I was almost there with thinking about adding the timedelta but I just did not make it well. Also I like constructing the timedelta by days-seconds because this gives me flexibility in rounding the microseconds if needed

Comment: @StefaniaR, ```datetime.datetime()``` will take care of microseconds as well. There is no need for all that conversion stuff. To check that, add a ```.%f``` to ```strftime()``` and you will see it. :-)

Comment: If you need nanoseconds resolution, take a look at [PEP564](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/).